# Transition button to show new text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to transition in new text when I hover over my button.

I've managed to transition out the box shadow and colour but can't seem to get the next to display.

My code so far:

CSS:

```
#button2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fea710;
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
         display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 12px 32px;
    font-family: arial;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    font-weight: 400;
      transition-property: box-shadow, background-color, content;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}

#button2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 #888888;
    background-color: #fec35c; 
    content: "New text";
  }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="mylink" id="button2">start a free trial</a>
```

Comment: That's not what the `content` propety is used for. It's intended for styling...not actual text.

Comment: You can use `content:New Text;` to append the New Text to the existing content. `#button2:hover:before{` Will add New Text in front of the existing text and `#button2:hover:after` will add New Text to the end of the existing text.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking to replace the text, have used @Kida solution which works but doesn't transition the new text in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="mylink" id="button2"><span>start a free trial</span></a>
```

In CSS

```
#button2:hover span {display:none}
#button2:hover:before {content: "New text"}
```

Comment: Thanks, that shows the new text but doesn't transition it in?